# I use tornado frameworks. I can use dict and list types in tornado templates, but when I use a object in the templates, it render as memory address

Tags: python, pagination, solr, tornado

for detail. I import Solrpy package to use. As for the document on Django project to introduce the pagenator. I pass the pagenator.page (Solrpage) object to tornado template 
but it doesn't work. I can'd use any method of Solrpage. instead it is rendered as a memory address.

below is the way to use the paginator , which is also the way I use

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

```
# Make sure page request is an int. If not, deliver first page.
try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
except ValueError:
    page = 1

# If page request (9999) is out of range, deliver last page of results.
try:
    contacts = paginator.page(page)
except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
    contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```

{% for contact in contacts.object_list %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}
    ...
{% endfor %}

{% if contacts.has_previous %}
            previous
        {% endif %}

        
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        
            ....

Comment: Please reformat your code.  Please Edit the question.  Please read the formatting instructions on the right side of page.

Answer (score 2):

Your class definition needs a `__str__( self )` method to render as something other than a random address in a template.